# What does "d-" in decimal number mean

Tags: decimal-expansion

I'm trying to implement some functions over Amazon's Ion Value, while reading [its document](http://amzn.github.io/ion-docs/), I found an example of decimal number is `6.62607015d-34` what does `d-` mean here? Thanks

Comment: I would say it's a typo and it means e as in exponent, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the notation `1.234e-56` for $1.234\times 10^{-56}$? Obviously, `1.234d-56` means the same but creates a value of type `decimal` instead of `float`.

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't float use f instead?

Comment: @KingLogic. In some languages that might be the case, but in this case the documentation certainly shows `e` under **float**.

Comment: @KingLogic e is a reference to exponent, so is used for the language's default real numbers format, which will be something binary such as float in Amazon Ion (technically a serialization format) or double in C#.